# A Schrödinger Love Poem?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

This question is for those who can see the romantic side of the Schrödinger equations...

My GF is studying quantum mechanics, and I was thinking to write it as an expression of a two-particle wavefunction. Romantic no? I have read a bit about it but I fear that it will be wrong (it will be geeky but that's OK!). 
Going something like this: We have two particles:

$$H\Psi_1=E_1\psi_1$$

$$H\Psi_2=E_2\psi_2$$

Adding two wavefunctions together gets you here, apparently:

$$\lvert \Psi_1 + \Psi_2\lvert^2 = \lvert \Psi_1\lvert^2  + \lvert \Psi_2\lvert^2 + \Psi_1\Psi_2^* + \Psi_1^*\Psi_2$$

Then I read somewhere that at this point, one can analyze the complex conjugate terms and see that the real parts add up, but the imaginary parts result in oscillations. So the particles at this point share a lot of togetherness but not too much, they have some space in the imaginary parts. They are joined but free. You get the idea.

Is there a romantic twist here or a sub equation or some analysis that would be not embarrassingly wrong in QM terms (doesn't have to be totally right either I guess — we're talking human hearts here) but some analogy between QM and human duality one might (if one were so inclined to expose the inner geek) infer from the equation?

What would a Quantum Physicist see in this equation that could stretch to a love poem?

Not sure if this makes sense or is just laughable. :) At a risk of getting downvoted here... But what can be more beautiful than a true amazing equation (which I don't understand much of beyond the general idea) ported to real life?

Physicist poets out there, would love your help to dig into this equation and find something in there that could have analogies in life ...

Comment: I upvote just for the laughs xD Good luck mate!

Comment: Do you know about "entanglement"?

Comment: It's Friday folks, just let this one be.

Answer (score 4):

Quick idea: the Hamiltonian is the time-translation operator. That means that a state $\Psi(t_0)$ at time $t_0$ can be evaluated at time $t$ like $\Psi(t) = e^{iH(t-t_0)}\Psi(t_0)$. If you have $\Psi(t_0 = 0) = \Psi_1 + \Psi_2$, then $\Psi(t) = e^{iE_1t}\Psi_1 + e^{iE_2t}\Psi_2$. So each $\Psi_1$ and $\Psi_2$ evolve differently depending on the eigenvalue $E_1$ and $E_2$ and $e^{i(E_1-E_2)t}$ is their relative phase difference. But because $e^{i2\pi} = 1$, you have periodicity.

That means that in the beginning, both the $\Psi_i$s are in phase, and as time goes on, they will experience some moments when they are out of phase, but at some point they will rejoin to be back in phase, and these ups and downs will alternate like this for the eternity.

You can make an analogy that although they might have moments where they don't quite get each other, they will always come back to the state when they were perfectly in phase, as they will always be bounded by their connection.

Good luck mate!